# Set values for sonata embedded admin

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I have two entities : Partner linked to Media.

I created my Partner admin and I would like to link an image for each partner.

I just want to upload a file in Partner Admin and then set the filename attribute of the media (depending on the partner name) when I submit the Partner Admin form.

For example I want to create "Stack Overflow" in Partner Admin. I pick up the Stack Overflow logo and when I submit the form I want to create automatically a new Media with filename "Logo Stack Overflow".

Can you help me to do that ?

Comment: Do your stuff in `prePersist()`

Comment: I used callbacks and prePersist method in my Partner class and that works perfectly, thank you !